# Python win32gui to scroll internet explorer/Firefox/Web browser window

Tags: python, win32gui

I've gotten it to work by sending it the up/down key and/or page down/up key but I want a more native way to do it, specifically to scroll X amount.

I've tried these:

```
win32gui.PostMessage(self.find_scrollable(), win32con.WM_MOUSEWHEEL, win32con.WHEEL_DELTA * 3)

win32gui.PostMessage(self.find_scrollable(), win32con.WM_VSCROLL, win32con.SB_LINEDOWN)
```

Without success.

However these work:

```
    win32gui.PostMessage(window, win32con.WM_KEYDOWN, key)
    win32gui.PostMessage(window, win32con.WM_KEYUP, key)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to try PyWinauto.
It will give you more tools to work with.